# exceptions.TypeError unhashable type list. How do I fix this?

Tags: python-2.7

```
import time

dictionary = {}

def add():
    x = int(raw_input("Please enter the hour of your event in 24 hour time"))  
    y = raw_input("Please enter the name of your activity")  
    dictionary[x] = y  
    print (dictionary[x] + " was added succesfully")  
    main()  

def view():
    theTime = time.localtime()  
    print "the hour is: ", theTime.tm_hour  
    theHour = theTime.tm_hour  
    x = dictionary.keys()  
    if x in dictionary:  
        print "The current event is", x  
    print "Your full shcedule for today is: ", dictionary  
    main()

def remove():
    print dictionary  
    x = int(raw_input("which time slot would you like to clear?"))  
    z = dictionary.pop(x)  
    print z + " was removed"  
    main()  

table = {
    1 : add,
    2 : view,
    3 : remove
    }

def run(x):
    table[x]()

def main():
    x = int(raw_input("Please select and option! \n\n1. Add an event \
\n2. View an event \n3. Remove an event \n4. Exit"))  
    if x == 4:  
        exit()  
    run(x)  

main()
```

Alright, So the only thing that is not working for me is the view function. After I add an event, and then I try to view it I get an unhashable type: "list" error. Why is this and how can I fix it? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning `x = dictionary.keys()`, which means that x is a list (of all the keys in the dictionary).  You then do `if x in dictionary`, which asks if the key `x` is a key in the dictionary.  But a list is mutable, so it's not allowed to be a key.

Did you actually mean to say `if theHour in dictionary`?

Comment: This worked thank you! Sorry. I hate being the new coder with dumb questions.